# About a little different negation of statement

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1. ∀x ∈ Z, P(x) → Q(x)
2. ∃x ∈ Z such that Q(x) ∧ ∼ R(x)
3. ∃x ∈ Z such that P(x) → S(x)

(1) The first one base on the rule "For all x, A(x)"    "There exist x such that not A(x)" So what I did is "∃x ∈ Z such that P(x) → Q(x) is false."

(2) For the second, base on the rule "There exists x such that A(x)"    "For every x, not A(x)" So what I did is "∀x ∈ Z, Q(x) ∧ ∼ R(x) is false" (no such that at here?)

(3) For the third, also base on the rule above, it should be "∀x ∈ Z, P(x) → S(x) is false"

I am not sure whether it is correct or not, could anyone help me to check it? Thank you!

Comment: Wherever this problem comes from, it looks like the intended answer involves expanding stuff like "$P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)$ is false" so that there are no English words.

Comment: @alphacapture How about "∃x ∈ Z such that not P(x) → Q(x) "? There are no English words "is false"

Answer (score 1):

In all three cases, you need to work the negation 'further in'.

For example, for the first one, you go from

$\neg \forall x \in \mathbb{Z} (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$

To

$\exists z \in \mathbb{Z} \neg (P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$

But you can bring the negation further in, since in general $\neg (P \rightarrow Q) \Leftrightarrow P \land \neg Q$, and so you get:

$\exists z \in \mathbb{Z} (P(x) \land \neg Q(x))$

Can you do the other two?